# Heroku: how to put file that is not in git repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Couldn't find the answer.

Is it possible to put some file in the heroku app files that is not in git repo? (Let's suppose I don't want this file to be managed by git, but my app needs it).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, the only way to push files to the heroku server is through git.

If it's something heavy like a music or video file (or any kind of file really), you can host it on Amazon S3 instead, and you might want to look at tools like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/amazon-s3-organizers3fox/ to help you upload files once your account is created.

Comment: Thanks. Its not a media or any other download content. I have something like XML file database.

Comment: amazon isn't just for media, if you need to change this xml file then amazon is the perfect place for it - you can even have it private and just make authenticated reads to load it in.

Comment: I just edited my answer to reflect John's comment, as indeed, you can store almost anything up there. See http://aws.amazon.com/en/s3/faqs/#What_kind_of_data_can_I_store